# character getting replaced by using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

```
String tempprop="(kfsdk)#";
tempprop = tempprop.replaceAll("[^\\s]\\)\\#", "\"?if_exists}");
System.out.println("1"+tempprop+"2");
```

I want the output as

> 1(kfsdk"?if_exists}2

but the output of this regular expression is

> 1(kfsd"?if_exists}2

Last k is getting trimmed, and I don't know why.

**if tempprop is ( )#, then output should be 1( )#2 only without "?if_exists**
This regular expression adds `"?if_exists` if no space is present else it returns the string as it is

Comment: use negative look-behind. The regex captures the letter before the `)` as well and replaces it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookbehind instead of `[^\\s]` because it causes some effect in the final output. That is, lookarounds does a zero width match.

```
String tempprop="(kfsdk)#";
tempprop = tempprop.replaceAll("(?<!\\s)\\)#", "\"?if_exists}");
System.out.println("1"+tempprop+"2");
```

Output:

```
1(kfsdk"?if_exists}2
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\s)` Negative lookbehind which asserts what preceeds is not a space character.
- `\)#` Matches the literal `)#` symbols.

Comment: @Naman See my answer as a followup for my comment. I'll edit in a reference.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude `[^\s]` from your capture, use the regex `(?<![^\s])\)\#`. Another option is to enforce letters using `(?<=\w)\)\#` or even forcing an opening bracket by using

```
out = str.replaceAll("(\\(\\w+)\\)\\#", "$1\"?if_exists}");
```

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more on lookaround (look-behind and look-ahead).